# How to remove all all options from NicEdit except Bold,Italic,UnderLine?

Tags: frontend, nicedit

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

You can see my goal here ...

I am using NicEdit in that i am getting so many options default But i don't want that all i want set only some of specific options.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the manual of nicEditor.

```
var NicEditconfig = {
   iconsPath : '/img/nicEditorIcons.gif',
   buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','ol','ul']
};

var NE = new nicEditor(NicEditconfig);
NE.panelInstance("IDofTextarea");
```